# Rails - How do I load a boolean variable initialized into the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I create an item in my application I want to load it as a boolean variable initialized to false, but everytime I check the object I create with the rails console it's initialized to null, so, how can I do that? (:

Comment: showing some code might be helpful

Comment: I've got something like this in the migration file:                    def change add_column :object, :favourite, :boolean end def self.down change_column_default :object, :favourite, false end end BUUUT! for some reason it doesn't load as FALSE, but null

Comment: Having both `change` and `down` isn't something you would ever do in a migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by setting the default value to false in your database migration.

ie. in a migration's `up` or `change` method:

`add_column :your_table_name, :your_field_name, :boolean, :default => false` (for a new column)

or:

`change_column_default :your_table_name, :your_field_name, false` (for an existing column)

Comment: basically in the command, but if I want to edit the migration file because I want to modify the database could it be something like add the line "default :false"?

Comment: If you've already run the migration, then you can roll it back, edit it, and then run it again.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply override the getter in your model:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def object
    super || false
  end
end
```

That way it doesn't matter if it's `NULL` in the database.